# fetch Postgres views definitions in correct order

Tags: postgresql, view

Is there a way I can extract the definitions of all the views in a given Postgres schema in correct order? For example if a view 'A' depends on view 'B', is there a way/script/query which outputs the definition of view B before view A?

I tried using AWS Schema conversion Tool but that didn't help either. It generates the definitions in random order.

Comment: You can try [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) which has `--table=`  parameter for selecting table or view

Comment: no luck @Sahap Asci. Views generated are in any random order

Comment: @Rahul can you tell us _Why_ you need it? By default pg_dump solves problems with forward references by creating all views as _empty_ and in a second pass only adds their respective SELECT statements when it is sure all the referenced objects already exist (at least as empty stubs).

Comment: my bad. pg_dump works fine. Thanks Guys